# Difference between two queries in TD

Tags: sql, teradata

Can anyone tell me if two queries fetch same result:
It is a fact and have millions of records. So can't do a trial in TD box.

Hi
Query 1:

```
SEL COUNT(DISTINCT SID) ACTIVE_USAGE FROM 
(
SEL  SID    FROM SIT.SBSCRBR
WHERE DT_DT BETWEEN '2015-07-01' AND '2015-07-25' 
AND PROCESS_ID < 202
GROUP BY 1
HAVING SUM(AMT) > 0
)A
```

Query 2:

```
SEL COUNT(DISTINCT SID) ACTIVE_USAGE FROM 
(
SEL  SID ,AMT   FROM SIT.SBSCRBR
WHERE DT_DT BETWEEN '2015-07-01' AND '2015-07-25' 
AND PROCESS_ID < 202 AND SUM(AMT) > 0
GROUP BY 1
)A
```

Comment: Is `sel` really valid in Teradata? Is it the same as `select` in standard SQL?

Comment: The second query is incorrect. You can't use SUM like that.

Comment: Yes, in Teradata we can write select as 'sel'

Comment: Of course you can test it.  Add constraints to reduce the number of rows, do it on a different table, in a non-production environment, all kinds of choices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using aggregate function in where clause is not allowed, so you may go with the first one.